# Should there be a [contact-detection] tag for Sprite-Kit questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

In Sprite-Kit, the 2D graphics framework for iOS, there is the concept of **collisions** which refers to the SK physics engine handling how physics objects interact when they collide (i.e. which ones bounce off which other ones) and also the concept of **contacts**, which is the mechanism by which your program gets informed when 2 physics objects intersect.

Objects may collide but not generate contacts, generate contacts without colliding, or collide and generate a contact (or do neither and not interact at all)

Collisions can also be one-sided i.e. object A can collide (bounce off) object B, whilst object B carries on as though nothing had happened. If you want 2 object to bounce off each other, they must both be told to collide with the other.

Contacts however are not one-sided; if you want to know when object A touched (contacted) object B, it is enough to set up contact detection on object A with regards to object B. You do not have to set up contact detection on object B for object A.

The vast majority (I estimate 95%) of SpriteKit questions tagged [collision-detection] are actually about contact detection. The 2 areas are related but problem determination is different.

Question: Should we have a tag for [contact-detection] to distinguish it from [collsion-detection]?

The distinction would be useful to those who know the difference (in SpriteKit terminology), but I suspect that people who are having problems in this area would not be familiar enough to use the tags correctly.

Comment: If you want to find an expert that knows the library well then it is useless, they all know about it.  Users pick [collision-detection] instead and did so 168 times before, plenty good enough as a contextual tag.  So no.

Comment: That's what I thought, but there's a part of me that objects to using the 'wrong' tag sometimes for my own questions and also thinks 'Oh - you meant "contact detection"' when I read most questions tagged [collision-detection] and is pleasantly surprised if it really is about collision-detection.